# Is there a way to tell PostGIS ST_Reclass to use double precision types?

Tags: postgis, raster

I have a raster of slopes with one band with decimal data type (32BF- 32 bit float) values from 0-90 degrees.
I use ST_Reclass to reclasify the values to 8 categories:

```
ST_Reclass ( raster, 1, '[0-1):0,[1-3]:1,(3-7]:2,(7-12]:3,(12-17]:4,(17-25]:5,(25-35]:6,(35-90]:7','32BF', 0 )
```

The first category is always empty, returns zero count whatsoever, so my guess is that it only works with the whole numbers. Is there a way to tell the reclass function that I want it to look at my data as they are decimal numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the answer after two days of experimenting with st_mapAlgebra. 
Never start naming the categories with 0. When I pushed the categories one higher, it works without problem. The new class expression is then:

```
'[0-1):1,[1-3]:2,(3-7]:3,(7-12]:4,(12-17]:5,(17-25]:6,(25-35]:7,(35-90]:8'
```